fast report doesn't show multi images in the docker
I'm implementing a report with the "fast-report designer". In my report I have to use 2 pictures located in the report title and report summary.
When I just put 1 picture in the report, the picture is shown. But when I put the second one the both pictures disappear or sometimes just the first one is shown.
I convert the rfx (the output of the fast-report designer) to a pdf via asp.net c# coding. The weird thing is when I run my code on the local system there is no problem with the report but when I publish it on the server this problem occurs and however the border of the picture box and its background color are shown but the image of it does not load.
Technical info:
my local environment is windows but I run my code via docker linux environment.
my server environment is linux and I build and publish the code on server via docker and I use this code for report in my docker file:
"RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus"
I tried these solutions and none of them solved my problem:

set the image of picture boxes with the c# code
put the second image in different parts of the report
checked the (overlay, size, and sizemode) of picture
used "afterdataload" event to load the image in the picture box
using a constant image


hi there, please provide some reproducable information, your question is not so clear

@FarkhodAbdukodirov I put more details in the question. Thanks for considering.
